# Why is my JavaScript code not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I have got some code that I got from [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LyndseyB/5S4mH/)

`$(function() {
    $('.toggler').click(function() {
        $(this).find('div').slideToggle();
    });
});`

```
<div class="toggler"> This is the title 
<div> This is the content to be toggled </div>
```

```
div.toggler { background:lightblue; cursor:pointer; }
div.toggler div { display:none; }
```

that I am trying to replicate on my own website, however it is not working. It displays everything but when clicked on, nothing happens. This is my code.

```css
div.toggler { background:lightblue; cursor:pointer; }
div.toggler div { display:none; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       $('.toggler').click(function() {
            $(this).find('div').slideToggle();
       });
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="toggler"> This is the title 
      <div> This is the content to be toggled </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

NOTE: You can also see what the code is meant to do with the JSFiddle link.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include the `jQuery` library in your `HTML`

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the jQuery library, if you want it to work.

```
<head>
    <link href="design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.toggler').click(function() {
                $(this).find('div').slideToggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Also a suggestion is that place your `script` tag with your code just after all the `HTML` just before the closing of the body tag, so that the JS compilation does not interfere with browser rendering.

Comment: Of course, you should use external JavaScript instead of putting it in your HTML, so it gets cached in the Client's Browser for faster load time when they visit your site again.

Comment: You can use googleapis to cache the jquery. https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

Comment: I added the jQuery Library where you suggested and tried the script in both spots (head and the end of the body) but it still does not work?